# Attribute 'public' can only be used in a non-local scope

Tags: xcode, cordova, swift, compiler-errors

A very technical error here and Google turned up nothing on this.

I am adding Cordova to a Swift Project.

I added a Bridging Header file and the Cordova build dependencies, and I did get autocomplete working (the Cordva CDV classes were auto-completing).

Everything was working fine until I suddenly got this error:

```
Attribute 'public' can only be used in a non-local scope
```

And my project just lit up with errors everywhere. Also tons of my functions stopped working.

[image]

Any suggestions as to what happened or what I could do to fix would be much appreciated

Comment: Answer about that error message below. As for *why* it's happening—my guess would be you lost a closing brace somewhere and things are being interpreted as out of global scope for that reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error shows up when you have `public` declared on a type that is nested inside a function or method—types declared in that context have only local scope, and thus can't be marked as public. Example:

```
func foo() {
    public struct Bar {        
    }
}
// Attribute 'public' can only be used in a non-local scope
```

Answer (score 42):

For future readers:

I agree with Nate Cook's analysis of the question, however my compiler was throwing this error because I was missing a curly brace (`}`) higher up in the file. For example, the curly brace after the default statement in the switch is missing. In this case it would throw the error on the `public var URLRequest: NSURLRequest` line:

```
public enum MyEnum: SomeProtocol {
    var someVariable {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return something
        default:
            return default
        }
    // <------- needs brace here
    public var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        // Code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! While switching to swift2, editing and adding guardes I miss one brace and almost started edit those private lets :)

Comment: Thanks this saved me a ton of time! Was missing a brace.